# Get service lifescope info in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

In a .NET Core 3 application, I can define dependencies within the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddTransient<Interface, ConcreteClass>();
```

Is there something that allows to get info about the lifescope of a specified dependency?

I mean, if I pass something like `typeof(Interface)` it returns something that I can use to find out that this dependency is Transient.

Comment: I'm quite curious on why you would need this. Would you mind sharing?

Comment: Nothing for real usage, I'm just writing an article for my blog about DI lifescopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
services.Where(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IDependency)).Last().Lifetime;
```

Comment: You'll better call `.Last()`, because the last `ServiceDescriptor` is the one that is used for injection of the service.

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand why it addresses the problem. That often reduces the amount of follow-up questions, and can really help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: Thank you all! It worked, I needed it not for a real project but for an article I'm writing for my blog (I'll not post the link here, I don't think it's correct for the other contributors. if interested, I'll try to add it to my profile). So that's exactly what I was looking for.